# in appium java client 7.0.0 is the driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME); deprecated, what is to be used instead?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am using the following environment:

```
PL: Java
Appium java client 7.0.0
Appium server version: 1.13.0
Device Samsung Galaxy S8
Android Version 9.0
```

but when try to enter the following code to click the Android Home key:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
```

But I get the compiler message that it is deprecated. 
How can I click the Home key?

Thanks for any Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **pressKey()** instead of pressKeyCode.

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;

//initialize AppiumDriver
((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));
```

The alternative way to click home button is:

```
String cmd = "adb shell input keyevent 3";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Thnaks for reply, 
teh issue with presskey is resolved after casting, 
but Androidkey.HOME is still not resolved. Still I get the following:
Add on demand static Import for "io.appium-java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey

also if I import the import classes you mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the correct KeyEvent library?

Comment: if first method didn't work for you, i have added the alternate method to click home button

Comment: Thanks Suban and sorry for late reply. 
The alternative way to click home button work for me.
Thanks for your Hint
just one Question where can I find the keyevent Number?

Comment: You can check [this link for android keyevent number](https://gist.github.com/ctrl-freak/9abb5aea0d89d7bd9df6a3d0ac08b73c)

Answer (score 1):

The keycode value for Android Home button is **3**.

Try using **3** instead of AndroidKey.HOME

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. This is tested and passed in the current latest io.appium/java-client 7.3.0.

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;


((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));
```

Further readings - https://discuss.appium.io/t/presskeycode-has-been-deprecated-java-client-6-0-0/22369